# Kendo UI masked textbox - unable to change default prompt char

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-maskedtextbox

I am trying to change the default promptChar for a Kendo MaskedTextBox. I tried with code:

```
 <div class="box-col" style="width: 300px">
        <h4>Enter a number</h4>
        <input data-role="maskedtextbox"
               data-mask="(999) 000-0000"
               data-promptChar="#"
               data-bind="visible: isVisible,
                          enabled: isEnabled,
                          value: phoneNumber,
                          events: { change: onChange }"
               style="width: 200px">
    </div>
```

However, the textbox still has '_' as the prompt character. Any idea why this is happening? How do I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `data-promptChar="#"` to `data-prompt-char="#"`

See working sample http://jsbin.com/xivede/1/edit?html,js,output